# How can I display when a user has submited a for?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, display, contact-form-7

I have created a site where people can subscribe and then acces their account page. (Using ultimate member) Very straight forward so far, now there is a page on the website where I have created a form qith contact form 7 for the users that are signed in to further sign in to “tournaments” or “clubs”.
Nmy question is, what would I need to do to display in their account page a something like “club 1” “registered”
“Club 2” “not registered”
Depending on if they have registeres to that contact form 7. If there is a way I will really appreciate it

I tried some code with chat gpt adding funtion.php code but it doesn’t seem to work. I ‘m not an expert working with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on user's role for its conditional. And since you are using a membership plugin, there should (always) that kind of function like conditional that can also works on every page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how do you keep track if a user is subscribed or not. I'd assume you have a database, if not, you should make one. Make a table in the database for all the users and add columns based on what you need. Like username, email, first name, last name, subscription, tournament specific columns etc. That way, you can save data for each user on whether they are subscribed to it or not. Accessing the database via php is very easy. You can check out [php:sqlite3 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php).

Once you have a database, you can run queries to add/update or delete columns/rows and their values. Check out this [query manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php).

Comment: You can query it like this:

`$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db'); $results = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');`
Once you know that they have subscribed or not from the database, you can choose to display the required components

Comment: I’m not really very good with code, I’v created the web with wordpress and I was hoping to find a pluguin or a way around code. I really appreciate it

Comment: I think you are heading towards a relatively complex website. I am not much familiar with wordpress plugins but you can add databases into your wordpress website. You will still need some level of programming to access data from your database. Or perhaps some other plugin that fills your requirement.